# Count Elements with a Particular Class in PHP

Tags: php, html, class, dom

I have this HTML:

```
 <div class="a"></div>
 <div class="a"></div>
 <div class="a"></div>
 <div class="b"></div>
 <div class="b"></div>
```

I want to count `div` elements with class `a`. How will I do that in PHP?

Comment: CSS class does not start with numbers. Use `a-z` instead.

Comment: Look DOMDocument class

Comment: @Raptor --> It was just an example. Anyways, I'll change it as what you've said. Thanks.

Comment: @Aliyah you can make use of [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) library to select the elements & count.

Comment: @Neyoh --> Yeah, I tried it but there's no function where you can get all elements with a specific class.

Answer (score 2):

You can do via `jquery` as below :

```
// Gets the number of elements with class yourClass
var numItems = $('.yourclass').length
alert(numItems);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need it to perform in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Μaybe you can `forEach` all of the `div`s, then use a RegExp like `^[a-z]` to match you `div`s class value.

If matched, set your iterator `+1`, finally return your iterator.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will output an array consisting of strings(in this case, strings that has div tags):
(Assume that this code is in the index.php)

```
 <div class="a">a</div>
 <div class="a">b</div>
 <div class="a">c</div>
 <div class="b">d</div>
 <div class="b">e</div>
 <?php

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$html = file_get_contents('index.php');

@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$a = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');

$key = 0;

foreach ($a as $divs) {
    $attr = $a->item($key)->getAttribute('class');
    if ( $attr == 'a' ) {
        $divs_array[] = $dom->saveXML($divs);
    }
    $key = $key + 1;
}

print_r($divs_array);
```

You will get this result:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => <div class="a">a</div>
    [1] => <div class="a">b</div>
    [2] => <div class="a">c</div>
)
```

To count the result, just use the count() method.